# Interpreting this Bus Schedule

Tags: translation

こんにちわ、

I am seeking some help to interpret the following bus schedule.  Specifically, I am interested in determining which section of this table deals with the travel times to 浄土ヶ浜ビジターセンター (Joudogahama Visitor Center) from 宮古駅　（Miyako Station).

If I'm interpreting this table correctly, the top row (C01,A01,C02,A02) are the bus routes?  Going down each column, taking the 9:00 column, the bus leaves 宮古駅 at 9:00 am and arrives at 浄土ヶ浜ビジターセンター at 9:13?

In the second table below, is it correct that the bus leaves the 浄土ヶ浜ビジターセンター at 08:33 and arrives at 宮古駅 at 08:50?

Thanks for the help.

[Bus Timetable to Jodogahama Visitor Center](http://www.iwate-kenpokubus.co.jp/uploads/300407_jodo.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm interpreting this table correctly, the top row (C01,A01,C02,A02) are the bus routes?

Yes. It appears so. The names directly below them seem to be the final destinations (shortened).

> Going down each column, taking the 9:00 column, the bus leaves 宮古駅 at
>   9:00 am and arrives at 浄土ヶ浜ビジターセンター at 9:13?

Yes, and that's Route C03 with final destination at 浄土ヶ浜ビジターセンター.

> In the second table below, is it correct that the bus leaves the
>   浄土ヶ浜ビジターセンター at 08:33 and arrives at 宮古駅 at 08:50?

Yes.

Take note of the schedules marked 土日祝運休, which means that buses don't travel at those times during weekends and holidays.